# Is it easier for Ionic to use data from a NoSQL or MySQL database?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, ionic-framework, nosql

Looking to build a database driven site using a PHP framework (not decided which yet, but the one that works best alongside Ionic)

Having the option of which database type to use, NoSQL or SQL. Which db works best with Ionic with the least configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Ionic to access database. Ionic is a client side framework for building hybrid apps which itself is built on top of angular js.

Furthermore SQL is a not a database, it is a query language used to communicate relational databases. The database can be MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle DB Postgre SQL and many many more.

You will use PHP (using the framework's DB access layer) to communicate with your database, write web services to communicate that data to you Ionic framework based app. So there is no question of what database is best to be used with Ionic. Though for PHP MySQL is usually the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

What Danish says is true, you can use whatever database you wan't for your project, remember that ionic is a front-end framework the same as angular. you might use mongodb with node js in the back-end or php mysql, or java + whatever. It just doesn't matters to ionic or angular.

Comment: As the product feed for the Ionic site used JSON, I had hoped to feed the products from my PHP framework site. Perhaps a framework that had good JSON compatiblity like Laravel.

Comment: hey @MeldaS, yes we usually use JSON and parse it with angular very easy to use, this is what we use a promise in the factory, send it to controller and parse it with `angular.fromJson(json);`, more info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson, I can give you an example of a promise if you need

Answer (score 0):

@Melda S., I personally prefer NoSQL. 
But whatever querying type you choose, it will always depends on what you doing, since when we talk about NoSQL, you have to consider that exists N "categories" of these databases - each one for an specific case.
Check these links so you can decide what will work for you.

http://www.ignoredbydinosaurs.com/2013/05/explaining-non-relational-databases-my-mom
https://www.mongodb.com/nosql-explained
http://nosql-database.org